# Monitoring and disconnecting users from an AirPort Extreme

Tags: snow-leopard, wifi, airport

Does anyone know a simple way to monitor who is connected to an AirPort Extreme, see the bandwidth they are using, and the ability to disconnect them or throttle their bandwidth usage?

I know for disconnecting two options would be
1. updating wifi password and restarting the AirPort Extreme
2. setting a limit by MAC address

but I am looking for something that wouldn't involve restarting the AirPort each time.

Comment: It's quite easy to spoof MAC addresses, so that isn't even bullet proof.

Comment: If you're using OS X server, you can use RADIUS to limit access by MAC address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there doesn't seem to be a native way to do this.

With regard to detailed bandwidth monitoring, the Airport Extreme supports SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) so if you want to put in a bit of effort, you could set up Cacti http://www.cacti.net/ and point that at the base station.

As far as remote disconnection of users, there is no way that I know of short of the two options you mentioned.